# Install Node.js on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using Puppet

Tags: node.js, puppet

I would like to install Node.js on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (running on Vagrant) using Puppet. In the base image Puppet 2.7.19 is pre-installed, and I would like to use the [`wildurand/nodejs` module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/willdurand/nodejs).

So I ssh into the Vagrant machine, and type:

```
$ puppet module install wildurand/nodejs
```

Then, Puppet fails with the following error message:

```
Preparing to install into /home/vagrant/.puppet/modules ...
Error: Could not install module 'wildurand-nodejs' (latest)
Directory /home/vagrant/.puppet/modules does not exist
```

So, I created this folder using:

```
$ mkdir -p /home/vagrant/.puppet/modules
```

Then, I ran the command again to install the module. Now it failed with a new error message:

```
Preparing to install into /home/vagrant/.puppet/modules ...
Downloading from http://forge.puppetlabs.com ...
Error: Could not find release information for this module (wildurand/nodejs)
  (HTTP 410)
Error: Try 'puppet help module install' for usage
```

According to Wikipedia, the http status code 410 means `Gone`, so apparently it cannot find the module any longer. Why is this?

And besides that: Why is Puppet complaining about the missing folder? Is it really my task as a user to manually create folders Puppet requires?

And, final question: Is there a better way to install Node.js using Puppet than what I've tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your spelling it should be:

```
puppet module install willdurand/nodejs
```

You had:

```
puppet module install wildurand/nodejs
```

I'm not sure why puppet is complaining about the missing folder, I do not usually install modules the way you are, which brings me to my other point - which is that you are probably better git cloning the module and using the vagrant provisioner to run puppet apply like it is described here:

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/puppet_apply.html

Comment: No problem, and thanks as well! Let me know if you run into any problems :)